# How do I get detailed file information if I only have the file name?

Tags: c#, visual-c#-express-2010

I have information about the output file name only.

[image]

How do I get the output size and modification date?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
    fbd.ShowDialog();
    textBox1.Text = fbd.SelectedPath;
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(fbd.SelectedPath);
    FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles();
    DirectoryInfo[] directorys = di.GetDirectories();

    foreach (FileInfo fil in files)
    {
        listView2.Items.Add(fil.Name);
    }
    foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in directorys)
    {
        listView1.Items.Add(dir.Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I have no idea what you are trying to say. I cant view the dropbox image. Can you try and explain further?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All those attributes are on the [FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) class:

```
foreach (FileInfo fil in files)
{
    listView2.Items.Add(
        new ListViewItem(
            new string[] {
                fil.Name,
                fil.LastWriteTime.ToString(),
                fil.Length.ToString()
            }
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: There is no overload that allows you to add an item like that. You need to first create a ListViewItem and populate it with your data and then add it.

Comment: Sorry - was thinking about the grid view, the above should now work.

Answer (score 0):

File.GetLastWriteTime will get you the last time the file was modified and FileInfo.Length will get you the length of the file if thats what you're looking for.